# How to best pass converted values of a Django model to context?

Tags: django

I have a model `Poller` that has a bunch of integer fields. I have a function `convert_thousands` that converts integer figures into short strings like so:

```
convert_thousands(1300000) # Returns '1,3 m' etc.
```

How to best convert alle of the integer fields and pass them into the context? Right now I'm doing it one by one by one..:

```
Foo = convert_thousands(poller.integerfield_one)
Bar = convert_thousands(poller.integerfield_two)
[..]

    context = {
        'poller': poller,
        'Foo': Foo,
        'Bar': Bar
        [..]
    }
```

Desired outcome would look s.th. like

```
[..]
    context = {
        'poller': poller,
        'converted_strings': converted_strings
    }

# and render in the template by {{ converted_strings.integerfield_one }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension here:

```
data = {
    'Foo': poller.integerfield_one,
    'Bar': poller.integerfield_two
}

# …

context = {
    'poller': poller,
    'converted_strings': { k: convert_thousands(v) for k, v in data.items() },
    # …
}
```

or if you want these in the context (and thus not in a specific item `converted_strings`, we can work with *dictionary unpacking*:

```
data = {
    'Foo': poller.integerfield_one,
    'Bar': poller.integerfield_two
}

# …

context = {
    'poller': poller,
    **{ k: convert_thousands(v) for k, v in data.items() },
    # …
}
```

Then you thus can render this with `{{ Foo }}` and `{{ Bar }}`.